# Windows phone 8: Can I work with gmail in my application

Tags: windows-phone-8

In my application, I want the user can send a feedback for me by gmail. Can I set an gmail account in my app, then it will send me the feedback to my email ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [EmailComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) API:

```
EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();

emailComposeTask.Subject = "Feedback";
emailComposeTask.To = "youremail@gmail.com";

emailComposeTask.Show();
```